# Starting Dialog from QuickAction Button

Tags: android, dialog, popup, quickaction

I have an app with a quickaction shown once a button is pressed. The quickaction shows a popup like in the Gallery 3D application for android, and when an action is clicked, I try to show a dialog, but I recieve a force close. Debug in Eclipse points to the slideDialog.show(); line, but I need that to show the dialog, right? Here's an example of one of those quickaction/dialogs.

> final ActionItem third = new ActionItem();
>
> third.setTitle("Adjust Brush Width");
>
> third.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_up));
>
> ```
>  third.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
> ```
>
> @Override
>
> public void onClick(View v) {
>
> ```
> slideDialog = new slideDialog(getApplicationContext());
>
>    slideDialog.show();
>
> slideDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
>
>  @Override
>
>  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
>
>   mPaint.setStrokeWidth(slideDialog.getSize());
>  }
>       });    }   });
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a sneaky suspicion that `getApplicationContext()` is not returning the right Context for your need.... have you tried passing in `Classname.this` into `slideDialog`... i.e. `sildeDialog = new slideDialog(Classname.this)` where Classname is the name of the class that you're currently writing in?

Comment: I have this SlideDialog already being used in the same class through the OnCreateMenu stuff, it just force closes when I try running the same code from a QuickAction. Is this possible?

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that getApplicationContext() is not returning the right Context for your need.... have you tried passing in Classname.this into slideDialog... i.e. sildeDialog = new slideDialog(Classname.this) where Classname is the name of the class that youre currently writing in?

Comment: what'd ya know! It worked! I sent it the classname.this instead of getApplicationContext() and it worked as it should. Thank you!

Comment: no problem! could you please indicate my answer as the accepted answer please(the green tick)? That would be great help, thanks.