# Unable to open AlertDialog from QuickAction

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm tried to display AlertDialog when an button in QuickAction is pressed.But my application crashes while trying to accomplish this task.I dont know what is causing the error.I also tried to use Thread.sleep to give time to QuickAction to dimiss properly and display AlertDialog but it didnt work.

I did research and found one question: [Starting Dialog from QuickAction Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708098/starting-dialog-from-quickaction-button)

This question is somewhat similar to mine but when i tried to replace getApplicationContext() with the MyClass.class i get an error saying that constructor AlertDialog.builder(Class) is undefined.

Following is the piece of code QuickAction and AlertDialog:

```
ActionItem editQItem = new ActionItem(ID_EDIT_Q, "Edit", getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.qa_edit));
    ActionItem deleteQItem = new ActionItem(ID_DELETE_Q, "Delete",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qa_delete_answer));
    System.out.println("Blah 1");

    mQuickActionQ = new QuickAction(this);
    mQuickActionQ.addActionItem(editQItem);
    mQuickActionQ.addActionItem(deleteQItem);
    System.out.println("Blah 2");

    // setup the action item click listener
    mQuickActionQ
            .setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos,
                        int actionId) {
                    ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);
                    System.out.println("Blah 3");
                    if (actionId == ID_EDIT_Q) {
//Here im getting error from here onwards when trying to display AlertDialog
                        et_question = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                        et_tag1 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                        et_tag2 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                        et_tag3 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                        et_question.setText(question);
                        et_tag1.setText(q_tag1);
                        et_tag2.setText(q_tag2);
                        et_tag3.setText(q_tag3);
                        tv_question = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        tv_question.setText("Question:");
                        tv_question.setTextSize(15);
                        tv_tags = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        tv_tags.setText("Tags:");
                        tv_tags.setTextSize(15);
                        ll_edit = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                        ll_edit.setOrientation(1);
                        ll_edit.addView(tv_question);
                        ll_edit.addView(et_question);
                        ll_edit.addView(tv_tags);
                        ll_edit.addView(et_tag1);
                        ll_edit.addView(et_tag2);
                        ll_edit.addView(et_tag3);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        builder.setMessage("Edit");
                        builder.setCancelable(true);
                        builder.setView(ll_edit);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Save Changes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        boolean Success = true;
                                        Editable ttv = et_question.getText();
                                        final String answer = new StringBuilder().append(
                                                ttv).toString();
                                        if (answer.equals("")) {
                                            Dialog mTag = new Dialog(
                                                    getApplicationContext());
                                            mTag.setTitle("One of the field is empty!");
                                            TextView tv2 = new TextView(
                                                    getApplicationContext());
                                            tv2.setText("Blank fields are not allowed.");
                                            mTag.setContentView(tv2);
                                            mTag.setCancelable(true);
                                            mTag.show();
                                        } else {
                                            String uname = qun.getText().toString();
                                            String question = qu.getText().toString();
                                            String question_time = qpo.getText().toString();
                                            String new_question = et_question.getText()
                                                    .toString();
                                            String new_tag1 = et_tag1.getText().toString();
                                            String new_tag2 = et_tag2.getText().toString();
                                            String new_tag3 = et_tag3.getText().toString();
                                            uf = new UserFunctions();
                                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                            db = new DatabaseHandler(
                                                    getApplicationContext());
                                            db.getReadableDatabase();
                                            hm = db.getUserDetails();
                                            db.close();
                                            String username = hm.get("username");
                                            JSONObject json = uf.updateQuestion(username,
                                                    question, question_time, new_question,
                                                    new_tag1, new_tag2, new_tag3);
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                            pd = ProgressDialog.show(ViewMyQuestion.this,
                                                    "Please wait...",
                                                    "Updating your question!", true, false);
                                            Thread thread = new Thread(ViewMyQuestion.this);
                                            thread.start();
                                            tagcombo = new_tag1 + "," + new_tag2 + ","
                                                    + new_tag3;
                                            qun.setText(username);
                                            qtag.setText(tagcombo);
                                            qu.setText(new_question);
                                        }// end of if else
                                    }
                                });

                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Blah 4");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                actionItem.getTitle() + " selected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    mQuickActionQ.setOnDismissListener(new QuickAction.OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ups..dismissed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Following is the Logcat messages:

```
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at com.vervecoders.cuqu.ViewMyQuestion$3.onItemClick(ViewMyQuestion.java:222)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at com.vervecoders.cuqu.QuickAction$2.onClick(QuickAction.java:162)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-05 18:01:27.158: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank You

Comment: try 
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivityName.this);`
instead of
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: it worked thanks Mohsin.If you want you can put this comment as answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivityName.this);` instead of `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`